# Updating PyQGIS Script

Tags: pyqgis, typeerror

At this link https://sisteme-ig.com/questions/10129/creacion-automatizada-de-lineas-perpendiculares-entre-una-ca#232721 @Xunilk shared a Script:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

p_lyr = layers[0]
l_lyr = layers[1]

epsg = p_lyr.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&field=distance:double(20,2)&index=yes"

dist = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 
                      'dist', 
                      'memory')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(dist)

prov = dist.dataProvider()

lines_features = [ line_feature for line_feature in l_lyr.getFeatures() ] 
points_features = [ point_feature for point_feature in p_lyr.getFeatures() ]

feats = []

for p in points_features:

    minDistPoint = min([l.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext( p.geometry().asPoint() ) for l in lines_features])[1]
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([p.geometry().asPoint(), minDistPoint]))
    feat.setAttributes([points_features.index(p),feat.geometry().length()])
    feats.append(feat)

prov.addFeatures(feats)
```

---

But from that QGIS throws me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: index 0 has type 'QgsPointXY' but 'QgsPoint' is expected
```

How can I change this Python code so it doesn't give this error?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  This is an English-only site, and your post was in Spanish. Nowadays there are multiple websites that can produce passable translations to and from English so I recommend using one of them to [edit] your question.  Please check out our short [Tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `QgsMapLayerRegistry` to `QgsProject` and `fromPolyline` to `fromPolylineXY`.

`fromPolyline` expects `QgsPoint` but `asPoint` method returns `QgsPointXY` instances.

Use like this:

```
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()

p_lyr = layers[0]
l_lyr = layers[1]

epsg = p_lyr.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=distance:double(20,2)&index=yes"

dist = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'dist', 'memory')
prov = dist.dataProvider()

lines_features = [ line_feature for line_feature in l_lyr.getFeatures() ] 
points_features = [ point_feature for point_feature in p_lyr.getFeatures() ]

feats = []
for p in points_features:    
    minDistPoint = min([l.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext( p.geometry().asPoint() ) for l in lines_features])[1]
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([p.geometry().asPoint(), minDistPoint]))
    feat.setAttributes([points_features.index(p),feat.geometry().length()])
    feats.append(feat)

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(dist)
```

Answer (score 3):

`QgsGeometry.fromPolyline`  want a list of `QGSPoints`, you are passing `QGSPointXY`'s. Convert them with `QGSPoints(thexypoint)`

So change the line:

```
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([p.geometry().asPoint(), minDistPoint]))
```

to:

```
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(p.geometry().asPoint()), QgsPoint(minDistPoint)]))
```